# Separate variable for each ng-include template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way in Angular to create a variable specifically to a template imported using ng-include? What I mean is that variable should only be accessible in that template included. For example:

```
<ng-include src="template.html" ng-init="varName = lists[0]"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="template.html" ng-init="varName = lists[0]"></ng-include>
```

On the current setup, the first init of varName is being overriden by the second initialization of varName, that's because they are in the same scope. What I want to do is varName should only inside that template's scope so that the second varName would be considered a different variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a directive with an isolated scope.

```js
angular
  .module("app", [])
  .directive("var", [function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
//      templateUrl: "template.html", this also works
      template: "<div><pre>{{ value | json }}</pre></div>",
      scope: {
        value: "="
      }
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-init="lists = [{ value: 1 }, { value: 2 }, { value: 3 }]">
  
    <var value="lists[0]"></var>
    <var value="lists[1]"></var>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes I tried that, but my problem is, within my template there are directives too and when I do that those directives doesn't work anymore. Any ideas?